# How to understand a fibre over a generic point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\def\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}$Consider a morphism $f:X\longrightarrow Y$, let $y\in Y$.

The fibre over $y$ is defined as $X_y=X\times_Y \Spec k(y)$, where $k(y)$ is the residue field of $y$ in $Y$.

If $y$ is a closed point in $Y$, then $k(y)=k$, the base field, and $X_y$ is the fibre over the point $y$, $f^{-1}(y)$.

But if $y$ is not a closed point, consider its closure $\overline{\{y\}}\subset Y$.

Then $k(y)$ is the function field of $\overline{\{y\}}$.

Let's replace $Y$ by $\bar{y}$,

so $y$ is the generic point of $Y$ (may assume $Y$ is irreducible).

Then what does the fibre $X_y$ look like?

I have an example:

$f: \Spec\{k[t,s]/(t-s^2)\}\longrightarrow \Spec k[t]$.

Let $y=(0)$, the zero ideal of $k[t]$. Then we have

$X_y=\Spec\{k[t,s]/(t-s^2)\}\otimes_{\Spec k[t]}\Spec k(t)=\Spec\{ k[t,s]/(t-s^2)\otimes_{k[t]}k(t)\}$

It doesn't look any familiar to me though. What's the geometric picture of this fibre?

Comment: If you fiddle around with this, you do find that it's just $k(s)$.

Comment: Oh yes, I see, thanks.

Comment: Yes, It's $X_\eta= Spec(k(s)) \longrightarrow Spec(k(t)) $, where $\eta\in Speck[t]$ is the generic point. This corresponds to a filed homomophism $f: k(t)\longrightarrow k(s)$, where $f(t)=s^2$.  f is an injection. However can we say k(s) is a field extension of k(t) ? The two fields are isomorphic though.

Comment: It's an extension of degree $2$.